# Not able to pass state from parent component to child component

Tags: reactjs

I am quite new to react, can anyone help me? I am not able to pass parent component's state as a prop to its child component. I am using typescript.
My parent component looks like this,

```
import DisplayResults from './results';

interface SearchResultsInterface{
    SearchString: string;
}

export default class Index extends React.Component<{}, SearchResultsInterface> {

    constructor(props: {}){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            SearchString: 'abcd'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
               <DisplayResults SearchString = {this.state.SearchString} />
        );
    }
}
```

I get an error, Type `{ SearchString: string; }` is not assignable to type `IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<SearchResults> & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>`.   Property `SearchString` does not exist on type `IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<SearchResults> & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>`.

My child component looks like this,

```
export default class SearchResults extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.SearchString);
        return ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Type your props for SearchResults component. Notice how your first component has ` React.Component<{}, SearchResultsInterface>` and the second only has `React.Component`. The first generic is the type for the components props and the second is for its state.

Comment: You need to specify the props type for `SearchResults`, just like you did with the `Index` component: `SearchResults extends React.Component<SearchResultsInterface , {}>`. You'll have to import the interface in the search results file, or re-declare it

Comment: Your parent component is rendering `DisplayResults` while the the second or child component code you showed is for `SearchResults`

Comment: It worked! Thank you!!